How to test the downloaded file content using jest
I have the following code to download a file on button click:
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', url);
link.setAttribute('download', 'fileName.csv');
link.click();

I wonder if there is a way to test the content of the downloaded file.
I tried to mock createObjectURL object and check the value of link's attributes.
jest
 .spyOn(URL, 'createObjectURL')
 .mockReturnValue('test');

expect(link.download).toEqual('filename.csv');
expect(link.href).toEqual('test');


What kind of test is this? Unit test? Api test, end-to-end test? You have tagged it as react-testing-library, but I do not see react code. This also implies you are testing the front end, so you do not have a back-end server running and cannot test the content of the downloaded file. There is no server to return the file to you. If you do an API test on a running back-end server, then you can test the content of the downloaded file
